# Gathering and extracting transaction details for analysis

Tags: transactions, blockchain

I am working on a project that requires me to study and analyze smart contracts in general and was wondering if there is a way for me to gather or retrieve many different transaction details from websites like etherscan. If yes, how do I then go about extracting the information from the transaction data into for example a csv folder for analysis? If no, how else can I go about approaching this project? I appreciate any help as I am still a beginner in the topic of smart contracts.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to gather data on etherscan, you just need to use go ethereum to collect all the transaction that ever have and will ever have on ethereum. It's gonna take a day to sync up but if you don't need all of them then maybe fast
sync and wait for like a day or two and you are good to go. Then you can use `geth dump` to get the data you want. You can check the go ethereum document here: https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/getting-started